# Robot class missing in pyrobot in python

Tags: python, selenium, importerror

I need to automate a file upload scenario in selenium webdriver.
Hence while searching for resources i came across pyrobot. I have installed the package.
When I import pyrobot like

```
from pyrobot import Robot, Keys
```

I get error in importing the package. When I went through the python files inside that package, there are no Robot or keys class.. and I get error as

```
No module named bs4
```

Please Help me to resolve this.

Comment: You sould install `beautifulsoup` too. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Comment: I have installed, still it is showing as this error ImportError: cannot import name helpers

Comment: I think you should report an issue for this: https://github.com/jmcarp/pyrobot/issues